# Upper bound of the energy of the graph

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Let $\alpha_n \leq \alpha_{n-1} \leq \cdots \alpha_1$ be all eigenvalues of a graph $G$ (where the eigenvalues of $G$ is the eigenvalues of its adjacency matrix $A(G)$).

Let $n = |V(G)|$ be the number of vertices of $G$. Prove that an upper bound of the "energy of the graph $G$", definded by $\mathcal{E}(G):= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha_i|$, is $\frac{1}{2}n(\sqrt{n} + 1)$, i.e., $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\alpha_i|\leq\frac{1}{2}n(\sqrt{n} + 1)$$

I once use the following expression, if $m$ denotes the number of the edges of the graph, then using the Cauchy-Schwatz inequality, with the easy fact that the trace of $(A(G))^2$, $\mathrm{tr}((A(G))^2) = 2m$, we have the following coarse estimate:
$$\mathcal{E}(G) \leq \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}^{2}}=\sqrt{n} \sqrt{2 m}=\sqrt{2 m n}\leq \sqrt{2\binom{n}{2}n} = n\sqrt{n-1}$$

but compared with $\frac{1}{2}n(\sqrt{n} + 1)$, it is bigger unless $n = 1$ or $2$ and I now face the difficulty.

Can anyone offer some help?

Comment: Hint: Turn the $0,1$ matrix into a $-1,1$ matrix in a natural way, then use your argument to bound the nuclear norm of that matrix. Use the triangle inequality for the nuclear norm to get back to the original matrix. By the way, your argument is tight for $-1,1$ Hadamard matrices, which is the intuition for this argument.